# Difference between different EventLogMessages.dll in .NET Framework folders

Tags: visual-studio-2010, logging, event-log

There are two EventLogMessages.dll files,

1. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll
2. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\EventLogMessages.dll

These files are not .NET files (they can't be dis-assembled with ILDasm). What are the differences in these two files?

I  used 2.0 version of the file for VS2010. Is it safe to do that?

If not, why should I be using 4.0 version of it?

-Datte

Answer (score 5):

There is no actual difference between them (except version info). The both dlls contain equal message tables, which are:

```
MESSAGETABLE
{
    0,      "%1"
    1,      "%1"
    2,      "%1"
    3,      "%1"
    4,      "%1"
   .............
    65535,  "%1"
}
```

So, IMO, there are two different versions of those dll due to different versions of .Net framework, and if your app was built for `target framework .Net 4 or higher` (it's only my assumption) and there is logging to event log in your app, `EventLogMessages.dll v.4.0.30319` will be used.

Comment: Apokal, how can I find where the app tries to write to eventlog indirectly. since I can't find EventLog by searching all solution. out company stop letting change the security permissions in regedit and now I need to change the app to not log or read from eventlog. thanks